# How to get firstname and lastname from email in POST?

Tags: html, post

Good Day Experts,

Just want to ask for any suggestion on how can get the firstname and lastname from email ad that being inputted by the user.

for example:

```
<input type="text" name="emailaddress">
```

user will input `Firstname.Lastname@email.com`

once submit the form,

I want to get Firstname and Lastname Separately and save it in database in column Firstname and Lastname.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? Heard of Ajax/ Jquery ? Using any scripting language? Gather data before asking champ

Comment: What language are you using for your backend?

Comment: what language is you server side application in? most languages will have a split method on strings, so you can do something like this (this is php) `$email = $_POST['emailaddress]; $email_components = explode(','$email)`

Comment: Are you sure about the format `Firstname.Lastname@email.com`?

Comment: Arvind Sridharan, I am using mysql as my back end!

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to convert your string to array
Try this one

```
$str  = "Firstname.Lastname@email.com";
$str = str_replace('@email.com', '', $str);
$str = explode(".", $str);
```

print_r($str);

It will output look like this:

Array ( [0] => Firstname [1] => Lastname )

But if not sure about the @email.com you can use regular expression instead of str_replace

Comment: Thanks zriel, what if i want to put the firstname and Lastname in variable $fname and $lname respectively? how can I do that??